# Error Running terminal command in Mac App

Tags: cocoa-touch, runcommand

I'm trying to run terminal command `pluginkit -m` in my mac app but it returns message `match: unauthorized discovery flag (PKDiscoverAll)`.But if I run `ls` command it works fine.

Can someone please explain how can I run `pluginkit -m` command or point me to documentation where apple explains why these command can't be run from an app. These commands run fine on my terminal.

Here is my code

```
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", "pluginkit -m"]
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh") //<--updated
    task.standardInput = nil

    try task.run()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```